# PDI Metadata Injection for JSON Input

Tags: metadata, pentaho, etl, pentaho-data-integration

Actually, I need to create a transformation which will read the JSON file from the system directory and rename the JSON fields(keys) based on the metadata inputs. Finally, write the modified JSON into '.js' file using JSON output step. This conversion must be done using the **ETL Metadata Injection** step.

Since I am new to Pentaho Data Integration tool, can anyone help me with the sample '.ktr' files for the above scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The same use case is on the Pentaho official documentation [here](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0L0/0Y0/0K0/ETL_Metadata_Injection), except it does it with Excel files rather than JSON objects.

Now, the Metadata Injection Step requires the development of a rather sophisticated machinery. And json, it is rather simple to build with a simple javascript. So, where do you get the "dictionary" (source field name -> target field name) from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, AlainD.

Comment: The link which you have provided is for Excel files. I am using the same functionality for the JSON files. 

We can go for Javascript if we know the exact no. of fields. Also, As per knowledge, dictionary(source field name -> target field name) is not possible in Javascript. So I am planning to go with the meta data Injection for JSON inputs.

Comment: As far as Kettle is concerned there is no difference between Excel/JSON/DatabAse/CSV/Hadoop once the stream goes out of the Input field. That's the beauty of kettle, and allow you to copy/paste the Excel example to the JSON.